# Request access to clients Google Business Profile (as frictionless as possibe)

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-business-profile-api

I'm trying to gain access to client's Google reviews and need access to their Business Profile. Is there a way that I can request this access through Google auth? Is there a better way to do it? I'm trying to make it as easy for the client as possible and don't want to make them manually do it.

Comment: If you use oauth you will only be able to access it via the API

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Does this mean that I can request access when they sign up  using Google's oauth? Is there any documentation for sending this request? Right now it seems that I will have to request to be a manager and then request Google to use the Google Business Profile API for that specific business which is super unsclalable. Thank you.